# Difference between Drupal Answers and Drupal Answers Meta

Tags: support

I have only just noticed the existance of Drupal Answers Meta site. As there is already Drupal Answers site.

I assumed that this is not different website to Drupal Answers. But, I found that there are different type of questions in this site.

I have searched for some questions in Drupal Answers Meta site, but I could not understand which type of questions we need to ask in this site and what's main feature of this site.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Drupal Answers Meta* is the site where you ask questions about *Drupal Answers* or *Drupal Answers Meta* itself. This means, as the help center says:

- Asking questions about how the websites work
- Asking questions of the community
- Posting bugs found while using *Drupal Answers* or *Drupal Answers*
- Suggesting improvements
- Proposing new features

Comment: If I understand correctly your answers. We need to ask the question regarding the features or posting bugs while posting Drupal Answers and we may not ask questions regarding drupal functionality in this site.

Comment: That is exactly correct.